# Why is .setUTCFullYear() and .setUTCMonth() return different results

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In this sample code to convert a string to a date:

```
function stringToDate(){
  var edate = "2015-06-01";
  Logger.log(edate);
  var input = edate.split('-'); 
  var date = new Date();
  date.setUTCFullYear(input[0],input[1] - 1,input[2]);
  Logger.log(date);
}
```

Logging the date returns "Mon Jun 01 20:07:45 GMT+01:00 2015", which is correct, as the month '06' - 1 = 5 corresponds to the month of June for the this.

However, this almost identical function:

```
function stringToDate2(){
  var edate = "2015-06-01";
  Logger.log(edate);
  var input = edate.split('-');  
  var date = new Date(); 
  date.setUTCFullYear(input[0]);
  date.setUTCMonth(input[1] - 1);
  date.setUTCDate(input[2]);
  Logger.log(date);
}
```

Returns "Wed Jul 01 20:10:04 GMT+01:00 2015". Some other values return equally screwy results. Why do I get a different result for 'setUTCMonth' then for 'setUTCFullYear'?

Comment: Set the UTCDate first then the UTCMonth

Comment: But why does this resolve it? I don't understand why you'd be required to set the day before the month. It seems arbitrary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the Date before the Month

```
date.setUTCFullYear(input[0]);
date.setUTCDate(input[2]);
date.setUTCMonth(input[1] - 1);
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCMonth
>
> If a parameter you specify is outside of the expected range,
>   setUTCMonth() attempts to update the date information in the Date
>   object accordingly. For example, if you use 15 for monthValue, the
>   year will be incremented by 1, and 3 will be used for month.

Each of the UTC functions has a similar note about out of range values.

So because of this:

`new Date()` gets the current date, and thus today being **5/31** the date is **31**.

There are some months without a 31st date, so 31 is outside the range for date so it is updated accordingly.

So if you try to set the month for say February without changing the date first,
The date would be 2/31/2015, but February only has 28 days this year so it rolls over to 3/03/2015

And in your case, if you try to set it for June, 6/31/2015, June never has a 31st date so again it rolls over to 7/01/2015. And so on.

So change the date first like I show above or set a default date when you create it:

```
new Date("01/01/2015")
```

Comment: It's just struck me how I never would have noticed this had I not been testing it on the 31st of the month, and how this easily could have gone unreported/unnoticed for years, and even if it had been reported, would have gone unreproducible unless it happened to be tested on the last day of the month...